# HTML5 interactive Infographic

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I haven't figured out any example about how to do something in the below link, so If you have any tutorial step by step or a code project it will be useful for me.

Link:
[Evoluton of WEB](http://evolutionofweb.appspot.com/)

Comment: I have looked at the source of the page: and it uses modernizr.js,
a plug in

Comment: Modernizr.load([{
        load: {
          'jquery':       '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js',
          'app':            'js/app.js',
          'check_browser':  'js/plugins/detectmobilebrowser.js',
          'drag':           'js/plugins/dragscrollable.js',
          'raphael':        'js/plugins/raphael.js',
          'addons':         'js/raphael.addons.js',
          'paths':          'js/paths.js',
          'browsers':       'js/browsers.js',
          'mouseStop':      'js/plugins/jquery.mousestop.js',
          ................

Answer (score 0):

There are using , jquery , raphael , galleria ,etc ... just look at the source code.